# Has any language or library found a way to implement a SOAP client without tons and tons of generated code?

Tags: web-services, soap, xml-rpc, rpc

I come from the .NET and Java world, and my impression of SOAP is that it always involves lots and lots of generated boilerplate code.  Is this a priori necessary?  Or have other languages or libraries found a way to do away with this?

Comment: Why do you care about the generated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Spring WebServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/) you can end up with JAXB generated classes (from XSD) only and use your own implementation which just uses these classes as method parameters and endpoint types.

SOAP itself can be seen as cumbersome protocol which requires expensive/heavyweight tools. It can also be seen as a thin wrapper of XML payloads which has great advantage - WSDL as a description language (which can also be seen both as heavy or as ubiquitous) which describes operations and parameters.

Back to Spring Web Services, here's the roadmap:

- you have only XSD
- you use XJC (or some maven plugin) to generate classes
- you write your own endpoint with methods which use these classes as parameters

here's sample endpoint:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "myMethod", namespace = "http://example.com")
@ResponsePayload
public MyResult myMethod(@RequestPayload MyRequest req)
{
}
```

I've written many *big* web services and writing by hand ~50 such methods is much more pleasant and effective then relying on generated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of the junk is necessary for SOAP, but the RESTFul stuff looks promising.i think the WCF Web API is worth a look as it implements a lot of the standard http stuff, but the WCF dataservices side of things looks cool too (OData?).

http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106

hope that helps

Comment: Oh, I agree.  The fact that REST eliminates the need for all that boilerplate is one of the reasons I like REST so much.  But I've had to work with a SOAP service recently, and it's just got me to wondering if all the boilerplate is a necessary part of SOAP or if someone's found a way to do without it.

Comment: i see.. i think the headers / envelopes are necessary because it has to carry around the definitions as well as their values.. where with REST, you just get the values.. so to answer the question, the way to do away with the SOAP requirements is to use REST.. lol. sorry i couldnt be more useful

Comment: Write about five REST clients for unrelated services and you'll find a lot of repeated code - boilerplate. You see it more with SOAP simply because it's a standard, and from one service to the next, there's a lot of similarity that can be pulled out as boilerplate or even configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want implement or consume simple WEB-services and do not generate tons of DTO objects, validate them etc, you may use [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite). It is primary intended for use from Groovy, what make it even more easy and attractive, and you off course may use it in just Java application.

Simple example of client WEB-servise consumption:

```
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx')
def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
    body {
        GetMothersDay('xmlns':'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
            year(2011)
        }
    }
}

assert "2011-05-08T00:00:00" == response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
assert 200 == response.httpResponse.statusCode
assert "ASP.NET" == response.httpResponse.headers['X-Powered-By']
```